# double pointer problem error passing through functions

Tags: c++, c, pointers, double-pointer

i have a two dimensional array  that i want to pass through a function

```
char blendModeOptions[18][16]={"Normal","Darken","Multiply","Color Burn","Linear Burn","Lighten","Screen","Color Dodge","Linear Dodge","Overlay","Soft Light","Hard Light",
    "Vivid Light","Linear Light","Pin Light","Difference","Exclusion","Hue"};

blendMode = KIT_CreateSelectOption(blendModeOptions,18,&blendModeRect);
```

and the declaration of the function is:

```
KIT_SelectOption * KIT_CreateSelectOption(char ** options,int size ,SDL_Rect * rect);
```

i got a warning :

```
note: expected 'char **' but argument is of type 'char (*)[16]'
```

inside the function i call a function `int KIT_AddOption(KIT_SelectOption *box, const char * option);` by this argument `KIT_AddOption(box,options[i]);`

my program crushes when i in this line of code in `KIT_AddOption`

```
strcpy(opt->name,option);
```

i have tried `char * option[16]` istead of `char ** option` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Provide [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a 2D array to a C++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-a-2d-array-to-a-c-function)

Comment: BTW this warning is actually more like an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define your array as array of pointers, instead of 2D char array.

```
char *blendModeOptions[]={"Normal","Darken","Multiply","Color Burn","Linear Burn","Lighten","Screen","Color Dodge","Linear Dodge","Overlay","Soft Light","Hard Light",
"Vivid Light","Linear Light","Pin Light","Difference","Exclusion","Hue"};
```